# adding opencv framework in Xcode 7 , getting issue framework not found opencv2

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, opencv

I am using opencv2 framework in iOS . i  have build  the opnecv framework using terminal and got opencv2.framework  in my directory. now from Xcode i am adding the framework using **addonther** framework in Xcode . and framework added like this 
[image]

and

in project navigation

[image]

and this is my search path

ld: framework not found opencv2[image]

**ld: framework not found opencv2
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

what is issue here . what is missing i am unable to find

Comment: Did your issue got resolved?

Comment: yes I have solved

Comment: How did you solve this problem?

Comment: @Sport How did you solve it can you share it with us?

Answer (score 3):

I was facing same issue when i am trying to add the opencv framework using addother framework in Xcode. And I had solved it by copying framework file into source code folder and then add it from that place.

My App folder screenshot URL: https://s31.postimg.org/99772tycb/Sceenshot.png .
Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Just Remove opencv2 framework from your project directory and add it again.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue with xcode 11.3 and openCV version 4.1.1, Got it solved by adding the new release of ovenCV 4.1.2 framework in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a bit late. But this can help someone. If removing and re-adding the framework does not work. Go to Build Settings-> Search Paths -> under Framework search paths: **Remove** `"Any Architecture | Any SDK".`

[image]